# Big5 conversion to UTF-8 in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, encoding

How do I convert this: 灣
to \u7063 in PHP?

The reason I'm asking is somehow that chinese character is stored as \u7063 in mysql (utf-8 encoding) but I cannot search it in db when they search with query '灣'.

**Additional Information**

My DB encoding is UTF-8, with Collation utf8_general_ci. PHP file was saved in UTF-8. I have tried the method suggested by Nambi, but it did not work, it returned ?? in console. See attached image[image].

Comment: So what do you have in the database, and what exactly does not work? You have `灣`? Or maybe the text `'\u7063'`?

Comment: `\u7063` has nothing to do whatsoever with UTF-8. It's some language specific Unicode escape sequence. "灣" encoded in UTF-8 would look like "灣", not "\u7063". Where does that escaped character come from to begin with? And I'm not sure at all where BIG5 comes into this.

Comment: What's your db encoding? What is the connection encoding? Did you save your PHP script file in UTF-8 format?

Comment: I have answered in above.

Comment: Turns out this was caused by json_encode I had. I am closing this question.

Answer (score 0):

try this code refer [here](http://eureka.ykyuen.info/2010/11/23/php-convert-big5-to-utf8/)

```
 function big52utf8($big5str) {

        $blen = strlen($big5str);
        $utf8str = "";

        for($i=0; $i<$blen; $i++) {
            $sbit = ord(substr($big5str, $i, 1));
            //echo $sbit;
            //echo "<br>";
            if ($sbit < 129) {
                $utf8str.=substr($big5str,$i,1);
            } elseif ($sbit > 128 && $sbit < 255) {
                $new_word = iconv("BIG5", "UTF-8", substr($big5str,$i,2));
                $utf8str.=($new_word=="")?"?":$new_word;
                $i++;
            }
        }

        return $utf8str;

    }
```

Comment: This does not work, see the attached image I posted.